# How to set up validation correctly in an Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, validation

I have validation error styling and error messages, I have problem when submitting the form. The error messages are shown but the styling doesn't work.

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched  
{  
    border: 1px solid #d70000;
    color: #d70000;
}  

<input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" [(ngModel)]="trip.city" id="city" #city="ngModel" required name="city">
```

As you can see above, I have the required attributed attached to the field.
But the styling is working only when the field is touched (as you can see from the styling).

Full template:

```
<form class="form_step_wrapper" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f1)"  #f1="ngForm" novalidate> 
    <div class="form_box">
    <div class="step_form form-horizontal">

        <section class="npc_box active">                                                      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" [(ngModel)]="trip.city" id="city"
                 #city="ngModel" required name="city">    
                <div *ngIf="city.errors && (city.touched || f1.submitted)">
                        <div class="error_message" *ngIf="city.errors?.required">
                                <span class="e_arrow"></span>
                                <i>Please enter city</i>                                                
                        </div>                      
                 </div>  
            </div>       
        </section>                                                                  
    </div>
    <div class="np_box">
        <button class="next_step">Continue<i></i></button>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I need to apply styling also when submitting, any idea what should I change/add?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your input as below, you can customize error color in css file of component.

```
 <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="city">City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" [(ngModel)]="model.city" #city="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && city.invalid }" required />
                        <div *ngIf="f.submitted && city.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="city.errors.required">City is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-ngmodel-validate

I update with your updated code

You need add `(ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()"` to your HTML

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-ngmodel-validate-kjvs6r

Comment: I've checked your demo  and it is exactly what I need but in my page it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you put full code of component and html to question?

Comment: added full template.

Comment: I've applied your changes but it doesn't work from some reason. I even tried to change your is-invalid to ng-invliad, still didin't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that setting the template variable name to "city" is causing the error, because it's a reserved word. Changing it will resolve the issue:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
   [(ngModel)]="trip.city" id="city" #city2="ngModel" required name="city">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3mbsfu)

Comment: Does the demo work for you ? if yes, could you please update it to show what doesn't work exactly ? Or could you tell in what it doesn't work ?

Comment: Added full template.